# library ('rvest') in R studio

Tags: r

while loading library('rvest') in R following error is coming:

> library('rvest')
>   Loading required package: xml2
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
>   Error: package ‘xml2’ could not be loaded

Comment: Have you `Rcpp` installed? If not, install it first..

Comment: I am having problem while installing even after installing Rcpp

Comment: library('rvest')
Loading required package: xml2
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package ‘xml2’ could not be loaded.......I think package ‘rcpp’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)